# Add "selected" in a <select> based on value from database

Tags: php

how do I select the correct value in a  when I get the value from a database on page load?

I have this code now, but when it runs it gives the attribute "selected" to every number after the given number from the database.

```
 <?php
   $i = 8; 
   while ( $i <=24 ) {
   if ($i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time']) { 
      $selected = " selected"; 
  }
   print ("<option value='" . $i ."'" . $selected . ">" . $i . "</option>"); 
   $i++; 
  } 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code to:

```
 <?php $i = 8; while ( $i <=24 ) {
   $selected = ($i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time'])?" selected" : "";
   print ("<option value='" . $i ."'" . $selected . ">" . $i . "</option>"); 
   $i++; 
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `$selected` variable inside the `while` loop:

```
<?php

$i = 8;

while ($i <= 24) {
  $selected = '';
  if ($i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time]) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
  print ("<option value='" . $i ."'" . $selected . ">" . $i . "</option>");
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Edit: Make sure you always set a value for each variable you use; it's a good habit. In your code you used the variable `selected` inside the print function, without always having a variable value assignment first.

Answer (score 0):

you never clear your $selected variable, basically once it finds a correct answer, $selected is set to " selected" and is no longer an empty variable, so each iteration when you call for it, it prints " selected" not "";

```
<?php
   $i = 8;
   while ( $i <=24 ) {
   $selected = ( $i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time']) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
   print ("<option value='" . $i ."'" . ( () ? )$selected . ">" . $i . "</option>"); 
   $i++; 
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the whole if statement :

```
<?php 
    $i = 8; 
    while ( $i <= 24 ) {
        echo "<option value='" . $i ."'" ;
            echo ($i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time'] ? ' selected' : '');
            echo ">" . $i . "</option>"; 
            ++$i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use

```
$i = 8;
while ( $i <=24 ) {
    $selected = $i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time'] ? 'selected' : ''; 
    echo "<option value='$i'  $selected>$i</option>"; 
    $i++;
}
```

Also, it's not necessary to use `.` when you have variables inside `"double quotes"` and it's better to use `echo` instead of `print` because `echo` is a language construct and it's faster than `print` function.

[**An Example.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yQaeGc)

Answer (score 0):

Check it :

```
<?php
$i = 8;
while ($i <= 24) {
?>

  <option value="<?PHP echo $i; ?>" <?PHP if ($i == $store_info['weekdays_open_time']) { echo "selected='selected'";} ?> > <?PHP echo $i; ?></option>
<?
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Hope it will definitely work :)